# Алгоритм выбора задач на исполнение

Tags: cron, алгоритм, php, оптимизация

Система мониторит некие объекты (в общем смысле) — несколько раз в день снимает с них списки параметров и сравнивает между собой по ходу времени, чтобы примерно локализовать некоторые события изменения.

Считывание кадого происходит порциями: 3 раза по максимум **L** параметров в 1 секунду. Потом надо ждать, перед следующими запросами. Из-за этого считывание крупных объектов может быть ощутимо длительным, прямо пропорционально "массе" (**M**) объекта, которая всегда известна заранее.

Считывание запускается по cron'у, пачками. Внутри пачки пока одни объекты ждут следующей "секунды", выполняются другие. Но всё равно из времени выполнения «пачки» около 50% – пассивный простой-ожидание. Увеличить размер пачки не позволяет память.

Собственно, память - это ограниченный ресурс. Сейчас worker сделан на php. При минимальной пачке занимает около 10 Mb, при рабочем размере — около 150. Т.е. запускать несколько мелких взамен одного крупного вряд ли есть смысл.

Вопрос эффективности: наполнять «пачки» так, чтобы время их исполнения максимально приближалось к интервалу крона, но не заходило на запуск следующей пачки. Т.е. что-то типа [packing problem](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B1_%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B).

Мониторинг некоторых объектов бесплатный, некоторых проплачен и должен выполняться почаще. А некоторые находятся в специальном режиме супер-частого мониторинга - должны точно попадать в каждую Пачку подряд (или каждую N-тую, но тоже чётко-строго).

Список объектов в мониторинге постоянно меняется.

Сейчас сделал примитивно: берется N самых давно-считанных объектов. N подобран эмпирически, и эффективность крайне низкая, т.к. иногда все в "пачке" имеют малую массу, и пачка отстреливается совсем быстро. А иногда пара "тяжелых" попадаются, и еле укладывается до следующего запуска из cron'а.

**Вопрос** — где почитать/как называется задача, какая модель её хорошо описывает, и как бы вы к ней подошли?

В простом случае - как организовать выборку заданий для очередной пачки? В более интересном — как бы организовать вообще весь механизм выполнения заданий?

Comment: @sergiks, в принципе это перекликается с задачами планировщиков в ОС.

Последний раз читал в книжке "Ядро Linux. Описание процесса разработки", автор -- Роберт Лав.

А вообще, думаю в куче книг по разному эта задача освещается.

Comment: Напомнило механизм распределения процессорного времени в соответствии с приоритетом процесса в ОС

(multi-)threading, priority, processor time вот это все

Но вы накладываете дополнительные ограничения, будете доробатывать

Comment: [Хороший ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26470743/556876) на этот воспрос мне дали на SO.

Comment: @Sergiks, почему бы вам его не перевести и опубликовать здесь?